# SPOJ Add reversed numbers

Tags: java, numbers

The code is as follows:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ADDREV {
    static int result,finalresult,firstNumber,secondNumber;

    //Can here be any problem?      
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter any 2 integers");
//Can here be any problem??
if(s.hasNextInt()) {
    firstNumber=s.nextInt();
    secondNumber=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Reverse(Reverse(firstNumber)+Reverse(secondNumber)));
}
s.close();
public static int Reverse(int i) {   
    result=0;
    while(i!=0) {
        result=result*10+i%10;
        i=i/10;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

On submitting this code as a solution to the SPOJ platform, and it says this is the " the wrong answer". Can you please help me why does this happening?

Input - 24 1

Expected Output- 34
The code works fine in my system fine but the program is not accepted on SPOJ platform.

Comment: whats the expected and actual output here? @Aradhya Jain what is your input? The code shared seems fine.

Comment: it works for me, so give more details

Comment: Please show all of the actual code that you are submitting to the SPOJ. How can we help if you are just showing snippets that may not be entirely inclusive of what you are submitting.

Answer (score 0):

[SPOJ ADDREV](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADDREV/)

The first problem is the class name, should be Main. Then the input format is an integer N followed by N pairs of integers. Finally, you should only output the solution to each test case.

AC code:

**Try it a couple of times more**. If not AC, then see it and try to understand it and try again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int result,finalresult,firstNumber,secondNumber;

    //Can here be any problem?      
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    while( n > 0 ){
        n--;
        firstNumber=s.nextInt();
        secondNumber=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(Reverse(Reverse(firstNumber)+Reverse(secondNumber)));
    }
    s.close();
    }
    public static int Reverse(int i) {   
    result=0;
    while(i!=0) {
        result=result*10+i%10;
        i=i/10;
    }   
    return result;
    }
}
```